# vite react app deloying. npm run build not working, Deploying issue

Tags: reactjs, vite

[image]

it says ../assets is outside src/ but as you can see it is inside the src/ and i deployed using github pages but the the link is not working

I tried mostly everything i could find for this issue.

Basically I'm not able to build my app successfully but npm run dev works just fine

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, your `src/index.js` is referencing `../assets` - which (by the looks of it) does not exist in the root folder of the project.

I think you're trying to reference the `assets` module (?) inside the `src` folder.

Try replacing `from "../assets"` with `from "./assets"` to see if that solves your issue.

Comment: Didn't work.

error message:

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets' in 'C:\Users\Pratikshit\Desktop\3JS\src'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './assets' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.

Comment: What does your `assets` folder look like?` do you have an `index.js` file inside the `assets` folder exporting the stuff you are importing (e.g. `threejs`, `aigroapp`, etc)

Comment: Yes exactly, i got the images and an index.js referencing those images